# How to deduce template parameter funct for for_each

Tags: c++, foreach, c++17

I am trying to remove entries from an `unordered_map`. A `vector` holds the keys that need to be removed from the `unordered_map`. I am trying to use `for_each` to iterate through the vector and call `erase` on the `unordered_map`.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, bool> sample_map = { {0, false}, {1, true}, {2,false}};
    std::vector keys_to_delete = { 0, 2};
    std::for_each(keys_to_delete.begin(), keys_to_delete.end(), &sample_map.erase);
}
```

I receive the error:

```
note: couldn't deduce template parameter '_Funct' std::for_each(keys_to_delete.begin(), keys_to_delete.end(), &sample_map.erase);
```

How do I correctly bind `sample_map`'s erase function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a template argument for the vector key_to_delete.

Anyways, this problem might be simpler if you manually wrote the code that looped through each key and called the function erase.

However, if you'd like to use std::for_each then you could bind it to the correct function to be called. In this case, one has to `static_cast` to get the correct function since erase has multiple overloads.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, bool> sample_map = { { 0, false },{ 1, true },{ 2,false } };
    std::vector<int> keys_to_delete = { 0, 2 };
    using type = std::unordered_map<int, bool>;
    std::for_each(keys_to_delete.begin(), keys_to_delete.end(), std::bind(static_cast<std::size_t(type::*)(const int&)>(&type::erase), &sample_map, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::for_each` is not quite suitable there. The code would be cleaner with `for`.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, bool> sample_map = { {0, false}, {1, true}, {2,false}};
    std::vector<int> keys_to_delete = { 0, 2};
    for (auto key : keys_to_delete)
        sample_map.erase(key);
}
```

With using `for_each` the code will be heavy for understanding. `std::unordered_map::erase` has overloads, thus it can not be used directly, you would have to create a functional object that calls suitable overloaded method, or use lambda.

Comment: why is for_each not suitable?

Comment: I have added more info in the answer. Look at other answers to compare which is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do what you want is to use a lambda like so:

```
std::for_each(keys_to_delete.begin(), keys_to_delete.end(), [&](const auto& key) { sample_map.erase(key); });
```